# Finding function definition on Linux mingw

Tags: c, linux, debian, mingw

I am trying to find the function definition for a function, let's say sscanf_s on Linux by doing

```
grep -r -i sscanf_s "/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/"
```

I did the below:

```
find / -name windows.h
/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/windows.h

find / -name libmsvcrt.a
/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a
```

Which shows me that it is the correct mingw folder. A friend ran the same grep command on a Mac OSX and he got the below output
[image]

Does anyone have any idea what I can do if I also want to get that output(to see the definition for the function) for the same grep command(just that he has a different path to mingw)?

Comment: You show your friend's output on the mac, but where is _your_  output on linux?

Comment: `gcc` accepts `-` as a file name representing standard input, so you could do something like `echo "include <stdio.h>" | gcc -E - 2>&1 | less`, and then at less's `:` prompt, enter `/sscanf_s` to search forwards for the function declaration, then enter `?^#` to search backwards for the line number and file containing the declaration. (But change `gcc` to the actual cross compiler `gcc` with its prefix.)

Comment: @stark It can be used to cross-compile for Windows.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I get no output when running the first command in my post, while he gets output(as shown in the picture) when he runs the exact same command.

Comment: @IanAbbott
I ran: echo "include <stdio.h>" | x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -E - 2>&1 | less
Then I typed: /sscanf_s?^#
But only got no pattern like this image: https://i.imgur.com/wthJmHj.png
I tried to click on "enter" after sscanf_s also, but same thing

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `#`. It should be `echo "#include <stdio.h>" |`.... And yes, you need to press "enter" after the `/sscanf_s` and after the `?^#`.

Comment: @IanAbbott
Nice seemed to work nearly 100% perfect, I got:
__attribute__ ((__dllimport__)) int __attribute__((__cdecl__)) sscanf_s(const char *_Src,const char *_Format,...);


While my friend got:
_CRTIMP int __cdecls scanf_s(const char *_Src,const char *_Format,...);

So the only difference is CRTIMP, does that convert to __attribute__ ((__dllimport__)) ?
The reason why I'm asking is I'm writing some code where my friend told me to specify _CRTIMP also , so would be nice to figure out this.

Comment: Preprocessor macros such as `_CRTIMP` will have been expanded by `gcc -E` (which runs the source through the C preprocessor). You will need to look in the actual header file that it found.

Comment: @IanAbbott

Nice, that line was in the header file. Now I know how to get this syntax. Thanks a lot for your help, appreciate it a lot! We can close this thread now.

Comment: @IanAbbott

I tried same technique with another function now: SystemTimeToFileTime
But that one gives pattern not found when I click enter after typing: /SystemTimeToFileTime

Are there any workarounds to this?

Comment: This is not a forum, therefore this is not a thread, and "closing" it means that your question is so bad that at least 3 others think it should not be answered. What you really want is an answer, and you can write it yourself. Later, when you're allowed to mark it, mark it, please. This is the way this site works. Questions are asked, answers are given, and future readers can see upfront if it's interesting for their issue. You might want to take the [tour] and read some of the [help] to learn more.

Comment: Oh, and if you don't find a function's declaration in a header file, it means that most probably you cannot use it, because it is not implemented in the accompanied libraries.

Comment: You should be able to use the same sort of technique, but you would need to change the `<stdio.h>` to something else - probably `<windows.h>`.

Comment: Also it seems to work better if you change `less` to `less -A`.